# How does it work the argument buttonIndex in cordova-plugin-dialogs?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

Hi I have problem with setting

```
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
//do stuff
} else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
//II do stuff
}
```

so is the app knows about buttonIndex in `if` ? Whether it knows only in `function onConfirm(buttonIndex){}`
about buttonIndex?
Generally is it about confirm dialog https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dialogs#navigatornotificationconfirm this dialog works but only display info
when clicked 'Tak' so buttonIndex == 1 (Tak is in English Yes) then I want to append `<li>` with name chipsy(in English chips) and a button to `<ul>` this doesn't work
here is my code http://pastebin.com/Wf7untcY

It is an issue with appending or with buttonIndex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it was an issue with wrong sequence of function 'content'

The **right** order

```
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
                                if (buttonIndex == 1) {

                                    var li = $('<li/>');
                                    var lv = $('#lv');
                                    var divP = $('<div/>', {
                                                'class':"ui-grid-a"}).appendTo(li);
                                    var divC1 = $('<div/>', {
                                                 'class':"ui-block-a",
                                                 text:'chips'}).appendTo(divP);
                                    var btnDel = $('<button/>', {
                                                 'class':"ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline",
                                                 click: function() {
                                                    li.empty();
                                                 }
                                    });

                                    var divC2 = $('<div/>', {
                                                'class':"ui-block-b"}).appendTo(divP).append(btnDel);

                                    lv.append(li);

                                    window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('Added chips to shopping list');
                                } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
                                    window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('Not added');
                                }
                            }

                            navigator.notification.confirm('Do you want to add chips to beer?', onConfirm, 'Basket Analysis', ['Yes','No']);
```

Comment: translated text from pl to en